# Programmatically import media

Tags: importing-exporting, media

I'm using media-7.x-2.0 and I would like to programmatically import media.

The workflow is this:

- uploader uploads an audio file via ftps
- a file watcher watches for changes in the upload directory and once upload has completed the file gets moved to the import dir and renamed.
- a mail is sent to the publishers with the file's length.
- whichever publisher is on duty that day imports the file via UI
- creates a post
- publishes post to social networks

So. I'd like to step in, after file gets moved to import dir and renamed the file should be imported to Drupal and the media library.

I have full root access and can do whatever it takes.

I'm guessing I have to somehow bootstrap Drupal and use the site's credentials. How do I do that and, step 2, how would I then use the media module's own functions to run the import?

Update:

Ok bootstrapping

```
<?php define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());

require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc'; drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
```

`getcwd()` because even if you give it the correct root dir bootstrapping fails with theme errors and whatnot.

So this is step 1. Step 2? How would I now import a file, let's call it `import/file.mp3`?

Comment: This question is being flagged a too broad. I think if you focus on the question on just one step (e.g. with a file in a directory how to do programmatically import it with the media module) you might have better success here.

Comment: Isn't that what I'm asking about? Is your gripe with the title or the actual question in the body? The steps are there so people understand the workflow that is happening.

Comment: Not griping, but just a suggestion if the question gets flagged as too broad. I can see a reviewer looking over a list of functionality and think you're asking a how to create this feature, not a specific question about how to use the Media module's API.

Comment: Ok, not a native English speaker. I guess I meant problem, not gripe. It's just what I read. Anyhow let's worry about that once it happens.